# How does one change title bar image in WPF Window?

Tags: wpf

How does one change the titile bar image (the top-left most icon) in WPF?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Icon attribute of Window is used to set Icon of a window.

```
<Window x:Class="WindowSample.MainWindow"

xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Title="WPF Window Sample" Height="350" Width="525"

Name="FirstWindow" Icon="Icon1.ico" >
```

The Icon property of Window class represents a window's icon at run-time. This property takes an ImageSource variable.

The following code snippet uses BitmapFrame.Create method to create an ImageSource and sets the Icon property of a Window.

```
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Icon1.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

You can read more from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/167/)

Answer (score 20):

**Easy way to add image to title bar:**

In your Project,
 Select - Properties - Application - Resources - Icon and Manifest - select the .ico image(always convert your image to .ico)

**Add this line(icon) in WPF Main window:**

```
Title="xxxxx" **Icon="xxxxxx.ico"**>
```

Comment: R click on project in the solution explorer menu > properties > application > resources

Answer (score 10):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="SDKSample.MainWindow"
Icon="WPFIcon1.ico">
</Window>
```

or in code

```
// Set an icon using code
Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFIcon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
this.Icon = BitmapFrame.Create(iconUri);
```

Source: [Window.Icon Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me (using Visual Studio 2017)

- Select menu Project/[yourprojectname] Properties
- Click Application tab (its the first one on top)
- Here you can browse for Icon, and it will be copied to your project

Answer (score 3):

1. Add ico file to project *Resources* and check as *Embedded Resource*
2. Set *Project->Properties->Icon* and choose from *Resources*
3. Run Project in *Release* Mode or *start without debugging*.

Comment: While these few steps was working for me, I am still puzzled why the default icon is showing in debug.

Comment: These steps don't make any sense in the context of visual studio. How do you add an icon to project "Resources"? Where is this "Properties->Icon" menu that you refer to? Etc.

Comment: R click on project in the solution explorer menu > properties > application > resources

Answer (score 2):

(1) When the icon is in the project root (same directory as the `*.csproj` file) and the XAML file is in a **sub directory**, then a **leading slash** is needed.

```
<Window ... Icon="/myIcon.ico"> ... </Window>
```

Similar for projects, where the icon is in the Resources sub directory.

```
<Window ... Icon="/Resources/myIcon.ico"> ... </Window>
```

(2) The **icon file** has to be **included to the project** (visible in Project Explorer). Also check in the file properties of the Project Explorer that the *build type* is set to *Resource*. (is the default setting)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Window Icon="youricon.ico"></Window>
```