# Adding Icon property to xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I'm trying to add an icon to a wpf window, but I'm getting an xaml parsing exception whenever I add the following line to my code:

```
Icon="myIcon.ico"
```

My window tag looks like this (and runs fine) without the Icon property:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="My Project" Height="562.356" Width="1058.204">
```

If I add `Icon="myIcon.ico"` before the `>`, I get an error on the `W` in `Width="1058.204"`

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an
>   exception.' Line number '8' and line position '58'.

So, the code erroring out looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="My Project" Height="562.356" Width="1058.204"
Icon="myIcon.ico">
```

I feel like I must be missing something very simple here. Based off of other posts here ([How to change title bar image in WPF Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101895/how-to-change-title-bar-image-in-wpf-window)) I feel like I'm doing it right.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: First of all import your icon file into the project. Then rebuild your project and at last try to add it using `Icon="path\to\icon\folder\file.ico"`.

Comment: @m.rogalski I imported it to the project, and used the entire file path as you showed, and it worked. Do you know how I could reference this file with out "C:\foo\bar" ? Ultimately, I need the users who install this program to view the icon, and they can't with it referencing my local machine.

Comment: I figured it out. Icon="pack://application:,,,/my folder/myIcon.ico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this with a little bit of help from m.rogalski's suggestion and using information in here:[How to reference image resources in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552618/how-to-reference-image-resources-in-xaml)

After importing my image to the project, I changed my code to look like this, and it worked:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="My Project" Height="562.356" Width="1058.204"
Icon="pack://application:,,,/my folder/myIcon.ico">
```

Answer (score 3):

> If I add `Icon="myIcon.ico"` before the `>`, I get an error on the `W` in `Width="1058.204"`

Add the `myIcon.ico` file to your project and set its Build Action property to Resource in the properties pane in Visual Studio.

You can then either set the `Icon` property of the window to a relative URI or a [pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) or you could specify the the icon as the default icon of your application under Project->Properties->Application->Icon and manifest.

Comment: I got the same issue and I just use the reference location and it works.  Icon="../Images/Myicon.ico" where Images is a folder containing the Myicon.ico under my project folder and icon is compiled as resource.